# News Impact curve shift

Tags: garch, leverage

I computed the NIC for both vanilla GARCH and EGARCH model specifications (with t(4)-student distributed innovations).

[image]

As we can see from the plot, no asymmetries are present, but the curve has shifted strongly upward (to make the curves visible together I put two different axis as you may notice).

- How can I interpret it? Any help is welcome

PS: this is what I get if I compare the two volatility estimates (the black line is the symmetric line).

[image]

Comment: What is the blue line in the bottom graph?

Comment: Oh yes, it’s just a regress line I computed from the scatter plot.